# Area inside an irregular ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, area

I'm working through a geometrical problem where I need to find the area on the 2D plane between different values of $L$, where:

$$L = \sqrt{(A^2 + x^2 + y^2)} + By\tag1$$

I'm struggling to find an analytic solution to the area of these weird ellipses, [here's an example of what they look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFJj2.png). The regular ellipse equation is:

$$1 = \frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b}$$
Or, by setting $L = ab$, one could write:

$$L = bx^2 + ay^2\tag2$$
$a$ and $b$ are the semi-major and semi-minor axis and the area of this ellipse is:
$$\text{Area} = \pi ab $$
But I cannot find a way to put $(1)$ into the form of $(2)$ nor can I find a semi-major or semi-minor axis for this shape so I'm a bit stuck on finding the area. I also tried finding the area using integration over some infinitesimal $dL$ and $d\theta$ angle but couldn't work out how to integrate them.

Comment: Notice $L = \sqrt{A^2+x^2+y^2}+By \implies A^2+x^2+y^2 = (L-By)^2$ and RHS can be simplified to
$$x^2+(1-B^2)\left(y + \frac{BL}{1-B^2}\right)^2 = \frac{L^2}{1-B^2} - A^2$$

Comment: There’s nothing “irregular” about them. They’re just offset from the origin.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was on the right track, in the end it was simple algebra which let me down.

Comment: @achillehui So to clarify, if I set a new coordinate $y' = y + \frac{BL}{1-B^2}$ and divide through by the right side of the equation I get:

$\frac{x^2}{RHS} + \frac{{y'}^2}{\frac{RHS}{1-B^2}} = 1$

Therefore the area is simply $\pi \frac{RHS^2}{1-B^2}$?

Comment: Yes (up to a square root), the equation for a standard ellipse should be $\frac{x^2}{a^{\color{red}{2}}} + \frac{y^2}{b^{\color{red}{2}}} = 1$ and area of your ellipse is $\pi \frac{RHS}{\sqrt{1-B^2}}$.